# Isn't there a preposition missing?

Tags: prepositions, ellipsis

> “They are exhausted families, sheltering in subway stations and schools: Ukrainians displaced by war face a difficult journey west."

Isn’t there a preposition missing between “journey” and “west”? Something  like "journey TO west" or "journey IN THE west"??

I mean, if the reader is not very aware of the context, it might be confusing. Is it grammatical to leave out the preposition there?

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed grammatical to say “journey west.” Here, “west” is just a modifier on the noun “journey.” Similarly, you can say, “on my **way home**” instead of “on my **way to the home**.” It seems to apply to nouns like “journey,” “path,” “road,” etc. that can be further described in terms of their *direction*.

Comment: A 'longer' version of 'on my way home' would possibly be 'on my way to my home', or, I suppose, 'on my way to home', although I don't think many people actually say that. I am certain, though, that nobody calls where they live 'the home'.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, in case "face a difficult journey west" without further knowledge of the context being that the case, onde might gets confused if that refer to already in the west a journey will set off OR a journey TO the west right?

Comment: @henrykearaudjo A journey west is always a journey TO somewhere to the west of the starting place.

Comment: @henrykearaudjo It is not confusing at all for native speakers, maybe this helps: it is the same as reading "westward" e.g.  "a difficult journey westward." What type of journey? A **westward** journey. A journey West.

Comment: @henrykearaudjo not only is it not confusing, I would argue it is the clearest way to describe this. "face a journey to the west." sounds okay, and it is understandable, but it just very unnecessary and sounds a little tedious.

Comment: what if it was refering to a journey  to would set off as soon as someone get to West? not a journey going to it

Comment: @henrykearaudjo - 'west' is not a place, it is a direction. There is always somewhere further west than you are.

Comment: A note about capitalization: the "West" (uppercase) means the Western world, the Western United States, etc. All of the usages on this page so far should be "west" (lowercase).

Comment: @henrykearaudjo If you meant to set off from somewhere in the west, you could say “set off from the west,” where “west” is understood to be somewhere further west than wherever the speaker currently is. However, in this context, there’s nowhere for that to fit in. As @/MichaelHarvey said, “west” is not a place, it’s a direction. It can only be used in *relative* terms.

Comment: @Annabeth Yeung, thanks I got it now. I was thinking as an alternative to interpret this text was a journey that would set off once one got to desired point in the west. As for expample something one would have to undergo once got to desired point in west

Comment: @Annabeth Yeung, arguably the text says Ukrainians have been displaced, so they might have already replaced themself somewhere to west from where they were and would start a new journey there get it?

Comment: @henrykearaudjo No, that is not how this phrasing is used. Not all idiomatic structures can be reached through logical reasoning alone. Logic tells us there are multiple ways to interpret this phrase, but proper knowledge of the language tells us there is only one.